# Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer? In a mobile app development

Tags: reactjs, navigation, native

Hi I had a problem with react native navigation can you help ?
I have 2 pages and these are blank and login. In blank page I have a button and when that pressed I want to change to page blank to login

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdB3P.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqCAs.png)

I tried everything but they didnt worked well

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be a dependency problem.

Try install them again.

> npm install @react-navigation/native

```
For expo project
```

> npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context

Also, install this.

> npm install @react-navigation/native-stack

> npx expo install react-native-gesture-handler

*If not problem solve check you components again(import export - default).*